# How to assign Dataframe column header names to column variable with iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am trying to iterate through dataframe header names and assign each name to the respective column values such that printing the name of each header will print the column data assigned to that header name. Current code:

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = "...data"

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, header=0, index_col=None)

for i in list(df):
    print i
    i = str(i)
    i = df[i]

print(cal_z)
```

result:

```
C:\...TFS_plot.py"

wavelength (nm)
Mix1_p
Ccal_p
Mix1_zero
Cal_zero
Mix_deriv
Cal_deriv
Unnamed: 7
Mix1_raw
Cal_rawzero
Mix1_rawderiv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....TFS_plot.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(cal_z)
NameError: name 'Mix1_p' is not defined
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am assigning the iterator to the variable df[i]?

example data:

```
cat dog
3   1
2   2
1   4

print dog
```

result:

```
(1,2,4)
```

Comment: Could you specify your question? What exactly are you trying to do? Currently the `i = df[i]` assigns the column to `i`, but you are not using `i` afterwards, so nothing happens.

Comment: Even if i change 'i = df[i]' to 'a = df[i]' it still does not work.

Comment: Your question is still unclear, what is your desired output? From your example it seems like you want new variables created, which names are the column names, and you want then to contain the respective column data as a list. Is that correct?

Comment: list or series.. doesn't really matter. I would normally do 'name = df['header name']'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is how to create variables with the same names of your DataFrame columns, and you want those variables to contain the values of their respective columns then this should help

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'cat':[3,2,1],'dog':[1,2,4]})

for i in list(df):
    exec(i + " = df[i].values")
print(dog)
print(cat)
```

your variables will have their columns values as lists.

```
print(dog)
# returns [1 2 4]
print(cat)
# returns [3 2 1]
```

all you're doing is get the columns name ( i ) and pass the corresponding columns to it (df[i].values) using [exec](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) for that.
Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does the exec function only take string values then?

Comment: Actually, i'm sorry, i gave the wrong link, as you can see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec), exec can take strings or code objects, in this case we used string argument as the line of code you wanted to execute.
exec( i + " = df[i].values" ) is the exact equivalent of dog = df['dog'].values or cat = df['cat'].values

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a way to do this. But as far as i now it would be better to just use a dictionary to store the variables.

use `list(df)` or `df.columns.tolist()` to get a list of your df's header
then use the `exec()` function while iterrating over this List and store the according values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"dog":[1,2,3,],"cat":[2,4,6]})
print(df)
```

output:

```
   cat  dog
0    2    1
1    4    2
2    6    3
```

list()-function

```
print(list(df))
['cat', 'dog']
```

exec()-Function

```
for name in list(df):
    exec("{}={}".format(name,list(df[name])))
```

afterwards you can call your list via the column name